TV-Show (maybe Movie) where four fathers/forefathers was a plot point
I'm looking for a TV Show, possibly a movie. Unfortunately I remember very little about it, not even if it was live action or animated. 
The one thing I do remember is that there was a plot point about confusion between forefathers/four fathers. The protagonists were told they had to look for the forefathers but they understand "four fathers". When they finally learn it refers to ancestors they could proceed past that hurdle fairly easily.
I'm pretty sure it's an English language show because the confusion wouldn't work as well in other languages. I'd say the show is more than five years old but it might be from the eighties or something. I really can't tell.
I hope the wonderful people here will be able to help me remember which show I mean despite how little information I can provide. Thanks in advance to anyone who tries to help.

Well, it would help if you narrow it down a bit more because I'm fairly sure this confusion had been played for laughs many times. Was it a comedy? Was it in color, at least?

Hmm, wasn't there such kind of confusion in Lethal Weapon 4?

any actor or character you reconized

My 2 cents - in movies, this is close to the plot in Mamma Mia!, and in TV, I rermember an episode of Dennis the Menace had a fore/four-fathers plot (or at least the joke).

@NapoleonWilson Yes! It was Lethal Weapon 4. The scene with Uncle Benny and the interrogation and the chinese word which translated to forefathers! If you'll post that as an answer I'll accept it . Thanks :)

@Walt It's been solved now but yes, I understood my question was sparse to say the least. Unfortunately, it was really all I could remember. :-( Asking it was kind of a 'hail mary'-pass :)

I'm fairly certain you are looking for the movie Lethal Weapon 4:

Martin Riggs and Roger Murtaugh, after escaping death from the previous movies are put on a hit list by The Triads. When blood thirsty mercenaries are on their tail they team up again with Leo Getz and Lorna Cole, a newcomer (Chris Rock) to finally put an end to the Triads for good.

There is a dialogue resembling yours, although you have it the other way around. In a bit of a botched interrogation Riggs and Murtaugh understand something about "forefathers", but it turns out it meant "Four Fathers", 4 leading figures of the Triads that the main villain wants to buy free with false money.
